# How to rename a file with a datetime stamp in python?

Tags: python, datetime, rename

I am currently trying to rename a file so that it has the datetime stamp as the name of the file.
Currently, I'm able to rename the file from what I originally have it, epoch time, to a date but not a time.

**My Code Currently:**

```
date=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(float(epoch)))
dst=str(date)+".jpg"
src=str(epoch)+".jpg"
os.rename(src, dst)
```

**What I Want to Happen *(OSError, the parameter is incorrect)*:**

```
datetimeStamp=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(float(epoch)))
dst=str(datetimeStamp)+".jpg"
src=str(epoch)+".jpg"
os.rename(src, dst)
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, that would be great.

Comment: Seems you're on a Windows PC which wouldn't allow `:` in filename. In that case, you can just leave those out: `datetimeStamp=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S', time.localtime(float(epoch)))`.

Comment: _"Doesn't work"_ is not an adequate description of what actually happens. Please [edit] your question to describe the behavior you currently encounter. Helpful links: [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I just put the error message that I received next to it.

Comment: It seems you got your answer from @mechanical_meat's comment, but in the future, please post the full traceback, because it usually contains useful information